# How is this "not a real question"?

Tags: discussion, site-policy

[How can I transition from freelancing back to the Corporate Workplace?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/9317/how-can-i-transition-from-freelancing-back-to-the-corporate-workplace)

I wrote the text specifically to make the query clearer by breaking it down into the 3 bullet points. It had a couple days to gather people that understood the question and participated in discussion, including an accepted answer and comments including people that voted to close it.

I see 2 problems here:

1. if it "isn't a question", but it generated discussion, how is it bad for the board?
2. It took ~2 days to close it, during which time the title was edited and a mod commented... occurrences which are rather validating and contribute to, shall we say, disgruntlement.

It's relative to a problem that's plagued a different SE board that I'm more active on where the mods down vote responses that provide an actual solution or answer that don't necessarily directly answer the question.

In my opinion: It's putting the rules above active discussion.

I don't want to come off as just bitching here (I won't deny it's annoying), I'd actually like to understand.

Comment: The question, at least as I read it, seems too broad and hypothetical. Also your first point about it generating discussion it's actually a bad thing. We prefer questions that can be definitely answered, not discussed. This is probably why people at that other SE site you participate tend to downvote answers that don't directly answer the question, SE sites are Q&A sites, not discussion boards.

Comment: I don't think anyone has ever put it that concretely before... That its not about discussion, it's about answers. It explains a lot. Thx.

Comment: Hi Monsto, based on the very valuable feedback you've received here on meta, you can edit your post on the main site to make it more concrete. Questions that are closed *can* be fixed and reopened by the community. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 5):

Let me inject my 2 cents.

I did not pay attention to the question on main site until I saw this question on meta.

I went to the subject question and stopped reading it as soon as I saw the word asshole.

If you want people to help you, please stop using those kind of words. If you act in your work place like the way you wrote that question, no wonder you're having problems.

I hope this answer kills two birds by one stone, i.e. answers both the question here and on main site.

Comment: it wasn't even a gratuitous use of cursing.  This isn't serious, is it?

Answer (score 3):

#### The message itself

> It's difficult to tell what is being asked here. This question is ambiguous, vague, incomplete, overly broad, or rhetorical and cannot be reasonably answered in its current form. For help clarifying this question so that it can be reopened, see the FAQ.

Ok let's look at this.

> It's difficult to tell what is being asked here.

Your question more or less says "I'm an asshole! help me not be an asshole! but I want to be an asshole" and gives no information about anything specific but rather a few vague statements about what this means.

---

#### Your specific questions:

> How do I work with the people but then get the heck away when they start into the cliquey talky crap? I've been busted a couple times rolling my eyes and walking away, but that's asshole.

What is this even asking? It's basically a "omg people suck" statement

> How the hell do I make it thru the day without staring at the clock and talking myself thru it "cmon man you can make it... there's a bottle with your name on it when you get home." I'm seriously out of the habit of punching a clock.

This is a personal problem and considerably more suited for a site dealing with productivity and/or addictions.

> As a pretty direct person in general, how do I not come off as just a gruff asshole?

This is completely vague, incomplete, overly broad, and rhetorical to boot.

---

> It's relative to a problem that's plagued a different SE board that I'm more active on where the mods down vote responses that provide an actual solution or answer that don't necessarily directly answer the question.

Wait, you are complaining that on a Q/A site, people downvote non-answers?  This isn't a discussion forum (well, meta somewhat is, but not the actual site).

- People post questions.
- People post answers to these questions.
- People vote on answers

Nowhere is there a "we have a long discussion." If you want that, go to [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/3060/the-water-cooler). But I suggest you act considerably less hostile and arrogant if you want people to even give you the time of day there....

---

#### My personal thoughts...

> I don't want to come off as just bitching here (I won't deny it's annoying), I'd actually like to understand.

You should consider step 1 of your recovery process: how you say things matters. If you intentionally come across as an arrogant asshole, don't be surprised if people react as such. You likely would have gotten a far better reception here if you HADN'T posted a complete rant that basically comes down to, "help me be an asshole at work. my coworkers don't like this - they are @#%#@ing idiots."

Comment: I'm not sure where you get hostile and arrogant. I asked a base question, called no one out, asked about the and the rules while following the required general process. What was hostile and arrogant?

Comment: @monsto read your question. Assume you are someone who is on this Q/A site because they like helping people with questions. Ask yourself how such a person (like me) would react to the tone, wording, and overall attitude in your post.